# Change margin of every quote block

Tags: margins, layout

I am with a question, I am trying to set the margin for every \begin{quote} block. I am already changing the text size by:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\scriptsize} %or maybe \footnotesize
```

Now I am looking how I can set the margin of every quote block to the left, I am doing it at every block, like example bellow. Is there a way to set this automatically? The text have two column of text per page, like most articles templates.

```
Concerning technological development, it is essential the identification of challenges and interests aroused from musical practices and its technological surroundings. According to Miller Puckette (2014), developer of the software Pure Data, one of the challenges for his field is the limited understanding about the consequences of software design on musical practices  \cite{puckettedeadly}:

\begin{quote}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{-0.7cm}
    %\footnotesize
    I think that musicologists might find some excellent research questions here. How, exactly, are the implications of software design choices insidiously affecting the practice of music composition and performance today? If software developers like me knew more about this, we could use the knowledge to inform our designs. The thing that limits us is not so much the time spent writing the code, as it is the limited understanding we have about what is needed.\cite{puckettedeadly}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{quote}
```

[image]

PS: Text is just a sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the quote environment in the standard classes is

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

You have two options. The first is to define (in the preamble) another environment, say, modquote, like so:

```
\newenvironment{modquote}
               {\list{}{\leftmargin=0.75in%
                        \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

You would then replace all `quote` environments with `modquote` environments.

Option 2, which only works if you don't plan on using `quote` unaltered anywhere, is to replace `modquote` with `quote` and `\newenvironment` with `\renewenvironment` above, like so:

```
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\leftmargin=0.75in%
                        \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

This would completely redefine the `quote` environment.

Comment: thanks a lottt that solved my problem and teached me about the newenvironment function, thanks! Worked beautifully!